# Windows phone 8 async web request with blocking user touch

Tags: windows-phone-8, restsharp

i need to know what is the best way to do a web request in windows phone 8.
as far as i go,i make it a 4 step process.

1. show indeterminate progress bar
2. block any user interaction
3. do request and process data
4. cancel progress bar and cancel block of ui

now my only problem is in step 2.

what would be the best way to block any user touch response while the network operation is going on and progress bar is showing?

for example i have username and password box and a button to login,i want when user press login,until the request is done,user ont be able to click on any ui item like username,password box or login button.

thanks

Comment: The best way would be to call a web service asynchronously by creating a background thread and updating the UI once its done..I dont think u need to block any user interaction ..

Comment: the thing you said is already done,but blocking ui is important,cause i dont want users to click the login button again before previous request is completed,or change the text value or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IsEnabled` property of `TextBox`'es and `Button`. Set it to `false` when you enter the Download function and return to true in case of error or just navigate/update ui is case of success.

Comment: ok,i was thinking about that,but i was looking for any method which will block the ui for the time being,but may be binding isEnabled to a property in a two way mode is the best solution.

Comment: Alternatively, you can show a Grid or StackPanel with opacity=0.5 over the all page to gray the UI and disallow any input. A popup can be used in the same way, there are few choices. However the timer should be made by you.

Comment: yeah have a popup on full size of your screen and change its opacity, you can create a custom control with popup and indeterminate progress bar and use it everytime you call a web service.Before calling the do work method of the background process set the popup and opacity, after you update UI from dispatcher change the opacity and disable the popup..

Comment: ok,im pretty much new in windows phone development,so pardon my ignorance ,but pop is a good solution,the qus is,can i make pop up not cancallable ? i mean user cant cancel the pop up with back press or anything?

Comment: You can try CustomMessageBox from [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/). There is fullscreen option.